# VB/SQL issue - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

new user here and your forum posts have been useful to me in the past. I have a problem that is beginning to seriously annoy me and I am wondering if you guys can lend me a hand!

My problem specifically is with this piece of code:

```
Private Sub drpUser_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles drpUser.DataBound
Dim newLabel As Label
newLabel = Page.Master.FindControl("lblA")
Me.drpUser.Items.FindByValue(newLabel.Text).Selected = True
End Sub
```

The server throws out 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' and references line 15, which would be:
    Me.drpUser.Items.FindByValue(newLabel.Text).Selected = True

What I don't get is when I run the debugger on my workstation, the code runs. It pulls data from the server just fine and identifies me. When I change newLabel to something else, like Label2, sometimes it will give me the object reference error and sometimes it will run just fine.

But here's the thing that's really getting me. When I switch label names and update to the server, the error it gives me references code that is still the same as the old one! So it will show newLabel even when I re-uploaded code that was renamed to Label2.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you should use the new keyword. Your code should look like

```
Dim newLabel as new label
```

Comment: Thank you. The debugger seems to be okay with this change. I will report back once I get the server to actually update the code...

Comment: Figured it out. It was a permissions error in IIS. The code checks the user and matches it with a drop down box of users. Because it had nothing to compare to, the compiler would throw an error there... yikes! Thanks for your help :)